# Using Serilog and ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

I am trying to connect Serilog logging with Application Insights, using this:
[Serilog Sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights)

I am not sure why it doesn't seem to be logging to ApplicationInsights at all, while the file-logging portion works as intended.

This is my code from Program.cs:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationHelper.GetConfiguration();
        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .ReadFrom.Configuration(config);
        var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration
               .CreateDefault();
        telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = config["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];

        //loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File("log-files/libtester-web-.log",
        //    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
        //    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);

        Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Events)
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           })
           .UseSerilog();
```

The appropriate section from appsettings.json:

```
  "Serilog": {
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "log-files/libtester-web-.log",
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "shared": true
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
"Properties": {
  "Application": "LibTester.Web"
}
```

}

It logs fine to the log-files directory, but my resource in AppInsights isn't getting the same logs.

I get these two messages in Output from adding this: 'Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));'

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"AppTraces","time":"2020-10-22T15:06:06.1140795Z","tags":{"ai.cloud.roleInstance":"MSI-970","ai.operation.id":"1b296d7eaa070941b54ef0b5019a7e18","ai.operation.parentId":"41f0aa970096b14a","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"dotnetc:2.15.0-44797"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request finished in 628.7215ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"ContentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8","ProcessId":"57840","ElapsedMilliseconds":"628.7215","SpanId":"41f0aa970096b14a","Application":"LibTester.Web","RequestPath":"/weatherforecast","StatusCode":"200","ParentId":"0000000000000000","MessageTemplate":"{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}","MachineName":"MSI-970","EventId":"{"Id":2}","TraceId":"1b296d7eaa070941b54ef0b5019a7e18","RequestId":"80000032-0003-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","HostingRequestFinishedLog":"Request finished in 628.7215ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8","SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics"}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"AppRequests","time":"2020-10-22T15:06:05.4273838Z","iKey":"e1281822-9ed6-4db3-8bad-0de7ce3689a7","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"0.0.1.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"MSI-970","ai.user.id":"POM78vd9lDKUjMr10/Qhgc","ai.operation.id":"1b296d7eaa070941b54ef0b5019a7e18","ai.operation.name":"GET WeatherForecast/Get","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.15.0+2c60e729d6512c31e5791ec93c9f7796d54fe426","ai.internal.nodeName":"MSI-970"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"41f0aa970096b14a","name":"GET WeatherForecast/Get","duration":"00:00:00.7411718","success":true,"responseCode":"200","url":"https://localhost:44337/weatherforecast","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"}}}}

Comment: Did you enable the [self log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog)?

Comment: I tried adding 'Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));' to my Program.cs, but I don't notice anything different from not having it.

Comment: Did you then attach the debugger and monitor the debug output?

Comment: I posted the only AppInsights relevant messages I saw in the Output window. They don't seem like they denote any kind of issue

Comment: Then perhaps everything is flowing to App Insights okay, and you're just looking at the wrong place to see  the data.

Comment: @JasonWard, In the output, I see there is a message`Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):`, which means that the instumetation key for application insights is not configured correctly.

Comment: @JasonWard, have you solved the issue?

Comment: Hi, @JasonWard! Did you manage to make it work in the end? I'm facing a similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove this section in `appsettings.json`:

```
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    }
  },
```

After remove it, I can see the logs are in azure portal -> application insights.

Here is `appsettings.json` in my test:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [    
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "log-files/libtester-web-.log",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "shared": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "LibTester.Web"
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, @Ivan Yang! How removing Serilog writer to ApplicationInsights makes sending logs to Azure? On my end didn't fix it.. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!